# Problem with React Linking : canOpenUrl always return false with Linkedin url on Android

Tags: android, react-native

I am having a problem with React.Linking and CanOpenUrl() on Android when I want to open Linkedin url.

Indeed I try to open a URL of the type https://linkedin.com/profil/id ... I check that the URL can be opened with CanOpenUrl(). If the Linkedin application is not installed on the smarphone, the URL is opened in a web browser otherwise canOpenURL() returns me false.

With other application I have no problem. For example for instagram if the application is not installed, opening the url in the browser otherwise opens the application.

The problem is only for Linkedin on Android.

I have modify the AndroidManifest.xml file like this:

```
<intent>
   <android action: name = "android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <android data: scheme = "linkedin" />
</intent>
```

It does not work.

Thank you for your help,